# Error when evaluating the CDF of normal distribution with SymPy

Tags: python, distribution, sympy

I would like to use the SymPy normal distribution as I do some symbolic calculations with it.

```
from sympy.stats import Normal, cdf
from scipy.stats import norm

norm.cdf(10, 10, 0.1)

def survival(x):
    y = Normal("x", 10, 0.1)
    return cdf(y)(x)

survival(10)
```

This code yields the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'reprec' referenced before assignment
```

It is noted that with the following adjustment it seems to work:

```
return cdf(y, meijerg=False)(x)
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General points:

1. SymPy stats module has some room for improvement. In particular, the documentation acknowledges that the CDF returned for normal random variables "needs some help" from `simplify` to become usable.
2. Floating point numbers, especially those that are not represented precisely in binary system, are poison for SymPy. You think you are passing in 0.1, but it's really `3602879701896397/36028797018963968` and a symbolic integration routine is having a fit.

Concerning the first point; the following example shows that `cdf(x)(t)` is a risky proposition.

```
>>> x = Normal('x', 1, 1)
>>> cdf(x)(1)
nan
```

The problem is that unsimplified cdf has division by `_z-1`. Better approach:

```
>>> simplify(cdf(x))(1)
1/2
```

Concerning the second: since the CDF is computed by symbolic integration, passing floating point numbers as parameters can make the life of integrator hard enough that it hits some deeply hidden bug using Meijer G-functions for integration. Use `Rational(1, 10)` or `S(1)/10` to create a rational number 1/10 instead of decimal 0.1.

```
>>> from sympy import S
>>> x = Normal("x", 10, S(1)/10)
>>> simplify(cdf(x))(10)
1/2
```